# How can i make regex with exclude certain words

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to  make regex which matches following urls

```
http://example/web-design/users/very-bad-user-423512/top
http://example/web-design/users/very-bad-user-423512
```

but don't match

```
http://example/web-design/users/very-bad-user-423512/left
http://example/web-design/users/very-bad-user-423512/right
http://example/web-design/users/very-bad-user-423512/bottom
```

I have tried this so far

`/users/.*/?(?!(left|right|bottom))`

its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt was almost OK. The following will work:

```
/users/[^/]*?(?:/|$)(?!left|right|bottom)
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qZ0oT7/1)

Your regex didn't work because the final `/` was optional, and the lookahead could match *right before the `/`*. I've added a condition that enforces either a `/` or the end of the string/line: `(?:/|$)`.

Comment: thanks for that , how can make that it also not matches `http://example/web-design/users/very-bad-user-423512/top/30` thanks

Comment: You simply add `top/30` as an alternative in the lookahead